# Grabbing Nonprofit EINs through scraping Guidestar or Citizenaudit search results

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I currently have a list of nonprofits and companies. I'd like to assemble their EINs computationally. I'd appreciate your help on how to do this.

My current idea was to go to the guidestar website (http://www.guidestar.org/Home.aspx), and if I could somehow navigate to the appropriate guidestar profile page, grab the EIN for the organization.

However, when I search an organization, like 'Somerville Community Corporation" into the guidestar page, I notice that there's a generic: http://www.guidestar.org/SearchResults.aspx When I click on the actual page, it pre-supposes knowledge of the EIN number in its url (23-7293380).

http://www.guidestar.org/organizations/23-7293380/somerville-community-corporation.aspx

I would appreciate any help on how I could get the EINs!

UPDATE:
Another alternative is to use citizenaudit.org
But, again, the url presupposes knowledge of the EIN. How to deal with this issue?

Comment: A search brought up this, which might be useful http://developers.firstgiving.com/documentation/nonprofit-search-api/ . If you try it use [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)

Comment: Along the same vein as @MrE's suggestion: http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToPub78Download.do

Comment: MRE and AP thansk so much! AP, What search terms did you use? I'm trying to find if there's a similar datafile of EINs for regular corporations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you download and unzip [the link which a-p has provided](http://apps.irs.gov/app/eos/forwardToPub78Download.do), you can then do something like

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
from operator import and_
import re

DATAFILE = "data-download-pub78.txt"

def get_words(s):
    return re.findall("[a-z]+", s.lower())

def build_index(items):
    word_index = defaultdict(set)
    ein_index = {}
    for ein, name in items:
        for word in get_words(name):
            word_index[word].add(name)
        ein_index[name] = ein
    return word_index, ein_index

with open(DATAFILE, "rb") as inf:
    incsv = csv.reader(inf, delimiter="|")
    items = (row[:2] for row in incsv if len(row) >= 2)
    words, eins = build_index(items)

def find_matches(s):
    wordlst = (words[wd] for wd in get_words(s))
    charities = reduce(and_, wordlst)
    res = [(eins[ch], ch) for ch in charities]
    res.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[0]))
    return res

def main():
    while True:
        s = raw_input("Enter all or part of a charity name, or nothing to quit: ").strip()
        if s:
            charities = find_matches(s)
            if charities:
                print("{} matches:".format(len(charities)))
                for ch in charities:
                    print("{}: {}".format(*ch))
                print("")
            else:
                print("No matches found.")
        else:
            break

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

which then runs like

```
Enter all or part of a charity name, or nothing to quit: Somerville Community
5 matches:
042740838: Community Action Agency of Somerville Inc.
222506464: Somerville Community Access Television Inc.
237293380: Somerville Community Corporation Inc.
432083625: Somerville Hispanic Association for Community Development Inc.
743021520: Somerville Community Library Association
```

Comment: you are amazing! i can't believe you did so much of the work for me!

Comment: could you help me understand what's going on here:       wordlst = (words[wd] for wd in get_words(s))
    charities = reduce(and_, wordlst)

Comment: I think I understand now. you are creating generator objects (as signified by the parens) and calling the dictionary that you created below. Your code is so interesting! i'm learnign a lot...

Comment: `words` is a dictionary; for each word, it keeps a set of all charity-names which contain that word. Wordlst then returns the corresponding name-set for each word in the input, and the `reduce(and_` finds the intersection of those sets, which is a set of all charity names which contain all input words. We convert this into a list of ein/name pairs, sort it by ein in ascending numeric order, and return it. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Hugh! Do you know where I can read more about reduce(and_ ? I've been doing youtube/google searches, but I only see the documentation which doesn't provide enough examples for me to understand. I'm finding that command particularly confusing.

Comment: `operator.and_` is just the `&` operator as a function. `reduce` repeatedly applies a function to pairs of values from a list to reduce them to a single value. So `reduce(and_, [a,b,c,d])` is the same as `((a & b) & c) & d`. Applied to sets, the `&` operator does set intersection; so it becomes the equivalent of `set_a.intersection(set_b).intersection(set_c).intersection(set_d)`. In the example above, this is `names_containing["somerville"].intersection(names_containing["community"])`. The `reduce` implementation is nice because it applies to arbitrarily long input chains.

Comment: amazing thanks! :) So is the broader style of this coding (using generators, reduce, and operator functions) favored because it is more efficient? is it appropriate to call this a style of code? I'm new to programming, and my knee-jerk reaction would have been to create dataframes from the EINs (with EIN and Name as separate columns) and grab specific items from the dataframe based on a search . The search would have used fuzzywuzzy or levenshtein distance to find a good match.

Comment: @user3314418: I've heard it called 'data flow programming'; it's _my_ favored style, but there are plenty of others. Levenshtein distance would be a more accurate solution, but much more expensive per call (against 827,000 rows); this allows me to pre-calculate everything up front and do a cheap lookup. If you could assume at least one word in the charity name would be an exact match, do union of sets (`operator.or_`) instead of intersection, then run levenshtein against that (greatly reduced) list? Might be the best of both worlds; first have to drop common words (and, the, for, ...).

Comment: Would it be possible to see an implementation of what you're referring to? I'd appreciate and example if you have a minute.